# How to import dump file oracle database to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I use oracle sql developer for export database after that i use bigdump import in MySQL.

Problem is I can't import it.

So it to many error as

```
Error at the line 2293: SET DEFINE OFF;
```

I would like to ask, what do I need to choose in order to export database using the oracle sql developer?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of `SET DEFINE OFF`, it is Oracle SQL*Plus command so - remove it throughout the whole file, it is meaningless in MySQL.

As of other errors (if there are any; probably, but you mentioned only one), it depends on what they are. MySQL <> Oracle, so you can expect certain differences in syntax or datatypes (e.g. `NUMBER` vs. `NUMERIC`). It means that you'd have to fix everything that causes problems, before successfully creating objects and inserting rows into your MySQL database.

I suggest you read [Migrating from Oracle to MySQL](https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/03/17/migrating-from-oracle-to-mysql) (written by Sten Vesterli).